Custom x-axis matplotlib
I have written this python code to plot normal distribution where I am trying to modify x-axis, however, it is not appearing
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# make greek symbols appear on plot
rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

mean = 0
standard_deviation = 1
num_points = 10**6 

# Range for smooth plotting, covering 3 standard deviations
x = np.linspace(mean - 3*standard_deviation, mean + 3*standard_deviation, num_points)
kde = norm.pdf(x, mean, standard_deviation) 

num_std_ticks = 4  # Number of standard deviation marks on either side
ticks = np.arange(mean - num_std_ticks * standard_deviation, 
                  mean + (num_std_ticks + 1) * standard_deviation,
                  standard_deviation) 

plt.plot(x, kde)
plt.suptitle("Normal Distribution", fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', y=1)
plt.title("(Empirical Rule)", fontsize=12, x=0.5, y=1.025) 
plt.text(0.5, 1,
         r'$\mu = ' + str(mean) + r',\sigma = ' + str(standard_deviation) + r'$',
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, ha='center', fontsize=10) 

ax = plt.gca()  # Get the current Axes object
ax.axis('off')  # Remove all axes
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)  # Show only the x-axis
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')  # Set the tick position to the bottom
ax.set_xticks(ticks)  # Set the x-ticks

plt.show()

ax.axis('off') seems to work fine to remove the axes, but the following lines of code not adding the axis back. I want the x-axis to look like this in the figure below (I know it is bit complicated but any help is appreciated).


Instead of  ax.axis('off) (which removes both the spines and the ticks), you could set for s in ax.spines: ax.spines[s].set_visible(s=='right'). Then ax.set_yticks([]) would remove the y ticks.

Here is an attempt using ax.yaxis.set_visible(False) to hide y axis, ax.spines[...].set_visible(False) to remove unwanted spines, and ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(ticks_formatter)) for a custom formatter on x-axis ticks.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker
from scipy.stats import norm

mean = 0
std = 1
num_points = 10**6

# Range for smooth plotting, covering 3 standard deviations
x = np.linspace(mean - 4 * std, mean + 4 * std, num_points)
kde = norm.pdf(x, mean, std)

# Main plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
ax.plot(x, kde)

# Titles
fig.suptitle("Normal Distribution", fontsize=14, fontweight="bold", y=1)
ax.set_title("(Empirical Rule)", fontsize=12, x=0.5, y=1.025)
ax.text(
    0.5,
    1,
    rf"$\mu = {mean}, \sigma = {std}$",
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    ha="center",
    fontsize=10,
)

# Deactivate y-axis, make it start from 0
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylim(0, None)

# Let only bottom spines visible
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

# Format x-axis ticks
num_std_ticks = 4  # Number of standard deviation marks on either side
ticks = np.arange(
    mean - num_std_ticks * std,
    mean + (num_std_ticks + 1) * std,
    std,
)


def ticks_formatter(x, pos):
    """Need to be adpated if different mean and std"""
    num_str = f"{x}\n"
    if x == 0:
        std_str = r"$\mu$"
    else:
        std_str = rf"$\mu{x:+.0f}\sigma$"
    return num_str + std_str


ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(ticks_formatter))
ax.set_xticks(ticks)

plt.show()



thanks, this works, but wow, it does have a lot of steps

Actually, for the ticks labels you could have just used ax.set_xticklabels, but I wanted to introduce formatting through a function, in case you wanted to extend it for other mean and variance cases.
